# In python how do you get the "last" directory in a path string?

Tags: python, path, subdirectory

I am working on a remote file system, where I don't have direct access to the files/directories, so I cannot check if a string represents a file or a directory.

I have the following paths I need to handle, where I have to get a hold of the "partition column":

```
path1 = "/path/to/2012-01-01/files/2014-01-31/la.parquet"
path2 = "/path/to/2012-01-01/files/2014-01-31/"
path3 = "/path/to/2012-01-01/files/2014-01-31"
```

In all cases, the deepest path (partition column) is "2014-01-31". Is there a way consistently to get this path in a single line of code, or do I have to do all sorts of checks of file names?

I was hoping to do something like:

```
import os
os.path.dirname(path).split("/")[-1]
```

But this doesn't work for **path3**. Does one need to have access to the filesystem to correctly identify the deepest directory, or is there some easy way?

Comment: Please clarify, do the files/directories exist? Or as those just strings? If only strings, why would `/path/to/2012-01-01/files/2014-01-31/la.parquet` not be a directory?

Comment: Well, I provided an example of strings, because I would like to solve this problem for strings regardless of the existence of files/directories.

Comment: Then your problem cannot be solved without further details. `/path/to/2012-01-01/files/2014-01-31/la.parquet` could be a valid directory and `/path/to/2012-01-01/files/2014-01-31` could be a valid file. How should those cases be handled unambiguously?

Comment: Also, are you considering those 3 paths independently? or simultaneously?

Comment: Independently. They are all real examples in my dataset.

Comment: If you don't have access to the filesystem, how can you tell, by just looking at the name, if what you have is a file or a directory? You might use some heuristics, but in the end, there's no way to be sure.

Comment: Well @ThierryLathuille, the conclusion is that you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically `la.parquet` is a valid directory name, so there's no way to tell just from the string, you'll need to introduce some manual logic. E.x. check for '.' in the name.

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> p = pathlib.Path(path1)
>>> p.parent.name if '.' in p.name else p.name
'2014-01-31'
>>> p = pathlib.Path(path2)
>>> p.parent.name if '.' in p.name else p.name
'2014-01-31'
>>> p = pathlib.Path(path3)
>>> p.parent.name if '.' in p.name else p.name
'2014-01-31'
```

You can be more precise (e.x. check `'.parquet' in p.name`) if needed.

Comment: I have *lots* of directories on my system whose names contain a `.`. The name can't be considered a valid criterion. The only reliable way is to check if you have an actual directory or an actual file, which means that you have to check the real file system, not just the path as a string.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I get your point and I say the same thing in my answer. If you have paths as strings only, without a way to check whether they are files, you need some domain knowledge to distinguish files from directories.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using pathlib. Here is a straightforward solution for the same.

```py
import pathlib


path1 = pathlib.Path("/path/to/2012-01-01/files/2014-01-31/la.parquet")
print(path1.parent.name if not path1.is_dir() else path1.name)
```

**[EDIT]**:- Handling cases when the last path can be a directory or a file

Reference

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name

Comment: This only correctly captures the path in path1.

Comment: True, handled the case accordingly and tested with 3 existing paths on my system

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this:

```py
pathlib.Path(path).parent if not os.path.isdir(path) else pathlib.Path(path)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for any of the examples

Comment: it does as long the files and directories exists..

Comment: Then add that to answer, and I will upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to get last directory name:

```
import os
path = "/path/to/your/directory"
last_directory = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path))
print(last_directory)
```

You have to make sure directory name is post fixed by directory separator, otherwise it will be considered as file.

Answer (score 0):

I expected there to be a function like "basename" to resolve this, but I guess as @Jatinder says, there is no way to differentiate between "directory name" and "filename without extension" without having access to the filesystem.

I ended up just using regex for my specific use-case, and I guess if example 3 was left out there would be a general solution checking for strings ending with "/".

Here my solution:

```
import re

# Examples
path1 = "/path/to/2012-01-01/files/2014-01-31/la.parquet"
path2 = "/path/to/2012-01-01/files/2014-01-31/"
path3 = "/path/to/2012-01-01/files/2014-01-31"

# Find match
for path in [path1, path2, path3]:
   print(re.search(r'.*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', path).group(1))
```